# Should I use collider for Unity RTS game attack range detection

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh-collider

I'm trying to make a RTS game with Unity. I currently have a working attack range checking method which checks if the target is within attack range by

```
if(target.colliderSize/2 + unit.attackRange >= Distance(unit, target))
```

This works fine if the target has a capsule collider which means the distance from it's center to it's edges are same, but if the target has a box collider(my structures), the distance from center to edges and corners are not the same. the unit will avoid the corners of the structure since the position is still out of range. I'm thinking using a trigger collider to represent the attack range and when they collide, they are in range. Is this method valid? Also, since it's a RTS game, there will be a large number of unit, will this heavily impact performance?

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty you can use whatever method works best for collision detection, in the past for how I've handled collision (in my case it was for enemies when doing melee damage in VR), I've used trigger/colliders and such with all different sizes and types.

For the performance side of things, at least from my experience, collision and trigger colliders don't fire off every frame so they don't cause any hiccups on that front. If you are doing something where you are doing a one-off check if an enemy or object is close to a unit, then it shouldn't be too bad. You can do things to mitigate what colliders or triggers with what if you play around with layers, having specific objects collide/trigger will help it mitigate condition checks for example.